# Hex values instead of line numbers in the stack trace

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace, line-numbers

I am trying to debug a Java program loaded to an embedded system by reading the output via serial port. When an exception is raised I cannot see line numbers in the stack trace. Instead there are some hexadecimal values. I suspect that maybe they stand for some memory addresses, but I am not sure at all. Here is a portion of the stack trace to give you the idea:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.is2t.web.rs.RestException
     at java.lang.System.@M:0x8009e7c:0x8009e86@
     at java.lang.Throwable.@M:0x8009f88:0x8009f9e@
     at java.lang.Throwable.@M:0x8008cec:0x8008cfe@
```

Is there a way to view properly the line numbers? If not, what is the best technique to debug without knowing them?

EDIT: The embedded system is an STM32 microcontroller and I don't believe they have a documentation explaining this particular situation.

Comment: You could start by telling us which embedded system you are using and whether they have any documentation on how to debug stack traces for that system.

Comment: Added the answer to the post

Comment: I suspect the only people who can answer this question are the vendors themselves. (Hopefully I am wrong, good luck)